# How to filter out rows based on other rows in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName 
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    Job VARCHAR(255),
    Action VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO YourTableName (Job, Action)
VALUES
    ('job1', '1E2B7D03-955E-46B0-BE35-0506C01CF68D/job1'),
    ('job1', '2CE87455-0AC5-4F5A-B0EA-66D8279E81D1/job1'),
    ('job1', '3CE87455-0AC5-4F5A-B0EA-66D8279E81D1/job1');
    
INSERT INTO YourTableName (Job, Action)
VALUES
    ('job2','1E2B7D03-955E-46B0-BE35-0506C01CF68D/job2'),
    ('job2','4E2B7D03-955E-46B0-BE35-0506C01CF68D/job2');
```

I need to get all the rows with job = 'job1' but if there is a row with job2 and the same Id inside the action then exclude the job from the result.

So the result for the values that are inserted will be:

```
('job1', '2CE87455-0AC5-4F5A-B0EA-66D8279E81D1/job1')
('job1', '3CE87455-0AC5-4F5A-B0EA-66D8279E81D1/job1')
```

because for the first job in list there is a job2 with the same Id in the Action column

I was trying to use a subquery but it either filters all out or nothing

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName j1
WHERE Job = 'job1'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM YourTableName j2
                  WHERE Job = 'job2'
                    AND SUBSTRING(j1.Action, CHARINDEX('/', j1.Action) + 1, 36) = SUBSTRING(j2.Action, CHARINDEX('/', j2.Action) + 1, 36)
);
```

Comment: Your Action column should be *2* columns, not 1. Or it shouldn't have `/job1` at the end and should just be a `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: If you fix that, it's actually a simple `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Well this is just a mock table, and I cannot change the existing one

Comment: i don't think your substring does what you think it does. why not just LEFT(xxx, 36) = LEFT(yyy, 36)

Comment: Create views the way the tables should look.

Comment: FWIW, it's not exaggeration or hyperbole to say performance can improve by **multiple orders of magnitude** if you separate the end of the action field to it's own column at insert/update time, instead of doing this at query time. Not to mention, suddenly this query gets a whole lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just* concerning your existing query, you can easily fix it because a GUID string is always 36 characters:

```
select Id, Job, Action
from YourTableName j1
where Job = 'job1' and not exists (
  select 1 from YourTableName j2
  where Job = 'job2' 
    and Left(j2.Action, 36) = Left(j1.Action, 36)
);
```

**Edit**

Dealing with your actual data(!), perhaps try the following:

```
select Id, Job, Action
from dbo.YourTableName t
where Job = 'job1'
and not exists (
  select * from dbo.YourTableName t2
  where t2.Job = 'job2' 
    and t.Action like 
      Concat('%', Substring(t2.Action, CharIndex('/', t2.Action) + 1, 36), '%')
);
```

Comment: With LEFT it works in the fiddle, but I forgot that in the original database it looks like `controller/{id}/action`

But why it works with left but not with substring if the result should be the same?

Comment: So the sample data you have provided is not actually correct then? Does kinda explain more what the query in your question was doing, but a complete waste of time trying to work with the data you provided though, right?

Comment: no, it should be looking like "test/1E2B7D03-955E-46B0-BE35-0506C01CF68D/job1"

Comment: @RheinmetallSkorpion based on that try the updated query above.

Comment: No, but It works in the fiddle so I mark it as a solution. I also tried to cast the substring in GUID but no luck. Maybe the SQL version is different or idk

Answer (score 0):

Like I mention in the comments, if you fix your design this is much easier. Your column, Action, shouldn't have the job name at the end; remove it. Then you can easily use a `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE YourTableName (
    Id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    Job varchar(255),
    Action uniqueidentifier); --Fixed this

INSERT INTO YourTableName (Job, Action)
VALUES
    ('job1', '1E2B7D03-955E-46B0-BE35-0506C01CF68D'), --Fixed values
    ('job1', '2CE87455-0AC5-4F5A-B0EA-66D8279E81D1'),
    ('job1', '3CE87455-0AC5-4F5A-B0EA-66D8279E81D1');
    
INSERT INTO YourTableName (Job, Action)
VALUES
    ('job2','1E2B7D03-955E-46B0-BE35-0506C01CF68D'),
    ('job2','4E2B7D03-955E-46B0-BE35-0506C01CF68D');

GO

SELECT Id,
       Job,
       Action
FROM dbo.YourTableName YTN
WHERE Job = 'job1'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.YourTableName E
                  WHERE E.Job = 'job2'
                    AND E.[Action] = YTN.[Action])

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTableName;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-)

---

If the difficulty you're having is fixing your design, you could do the following to fix the column `Action`:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.YourTableName
SET Action = LEFT(Action,CHARINDEX('/',Action+'/'));

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName ALTER COLUMN Action uniqueidentifier;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r15Gm0tr)

Comment: It is not possible to change the design

Comment: Then you could use the expression I use in the `UPDATE` in ` CROSS APPLY` to a `VALUES` table construct, however, performance will be far worse if this is a well indexed table.

Comment: Or can you, at least, add a computed column to the table, @RheinmetallSkorpion ? Then you can ignore the badly designed column.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do modification to the database nor to the data, this column contains paths to the controllers like `controller/{id}/action and this is the only column in this table I can do comparison between the rows

Comment: Perhaps you should be talking to someone who *can* fix the design then.